# A foreign key in the view details

Tags: python, django, templates, view, django-queryset

I have a django app where you want to display all images tracked to a particular gallery, but I get the error: 'GalleryDetailsView1' object has no attribute 'gallery'

**Model**

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='paint/%Y/%m/%d')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Gallery"
        verbose_name_plural = " Galleries"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Paint(models.Model):
    AVAILABLE = "Available"
    NOT_AVAILABLE = "Not available"
    STATUS_PAINT = (
        (AVAILABLE, u"Dostępny"),
        (NOT_AVAILABLE, u"Nie dostępny")
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='paint_set')
    paint = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='paint/%Y/%m/%d')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_PAINT, default=AVAILABLE, max_length=50)
```

**views**

```
class GalleryList(generic.ListView):
    model = Gallery
    context_object_name = "list"
    template_name = "www/gallery_list.html"


class GalleryDetailsView1(generic.DetailView):
    context_object_name = "images1"
    template_name = "www/gallery_details1.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gallery.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).paint_set.all()
```

**template: gallery_details1**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}


{% for i in images1 %}

{{ i.title }}
<hr>
{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}

{% block content_bottom %}{% endblock content_bottom %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the gallery `pk` somehow when you do your request. For example, as a part of your URL, and then get it from `self.kwargs['gallery_pk']` (the `gallery_pk` bit will depend on your implementation) in the view:

```
url(r'^api/gallery/(?P<gallery_pk>\d+)/paintset$', GalleryDetailsView1.as_view())
```

You can then return

```
self.get_object().paint_set.all()
```

as your query set.

The last but not the least, the `related_name` argument in the gallery field definion should be `"paint_set"` for it to work.

Comment: Sorry I have to ask this but did you test with your old url or the new one? Also, are you sure the object with the primary key exists?

Comment: Here is my url: `url(r'^gallery1/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', GalleryDetailsView1.as_view(), name="gallery_details1"),`

Comment: Did you add the trailing slash when you tested?

Comment: my output: `
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery1/3/
Raised by:  www.views.GalleryDetailsView1

No Picture found matching the query
`

Comment: What does `Picture` represent in your app?

Comment: I think this is image in model Gallery

Comment: Actually the model in that view should be `Gallery`, not `Paint` if I understood your code correctly.